# T4MVC and Area Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following area route registration method:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Registers the area.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        // terminal customer url
        context.MapRoute("TerminalCustomer", "Terminal/Customer/{action}/{id}", new { controller = MVCt4.TerminalArea.Customer.Name, action = MVCt4.TerminalArea.Customer.ActionNames.Index, id = string.Empty });

        // terminal inbound pattern url
        context.MapRoute("TerminalInboundPattern","Terminal/InboundPattern/{action}/{id}",new { controller = MVCt4.TerminalArea.InboundPattern.Name, action = MVCt4.TerminalArea.InboundPattern.ActionNames.Index, id = string.Empty });

        // terminal outbound pattern url
        context.MapRoute("TerminalOutboundPattern","Terminal/OutboundPattern/{action}/{id}",new { controller = MVCt4.TerminalArea.OutboundPattern.Name, action = MVCt4.TerminalArea.OutboundPattern.ActionNames.Index, id = string.Empty });

        // terminal inbound shipment url
        context.MapRoute("TerminalInboundShipment", "Terminal/InboundShipment/{action}/{id}", new { controller = MVCt4.TerminalArea.InboundShipment, action = MVCt4.TerminalArea.InboundShipment.ActionNames.Index, id = string.Empty });

        // terminal outbound shipment url
        context.MapRoute("TerminalOutboundShipment", "Terminal/OutboundShipment/{action}/{id}", new { controller = MVCt4.TerminalArea.OutboundShipment, action = MVCt4.TerminalArea.OutboundShipment.ActionNames.Index, id = string.Empty });
    }
```

It works fine as is, but when I change to the typesafe and no magic way of like this:

```
            context.MapRoute("TerminalOutboundShipment", "Terminal/OutboundShipment/{action}/{id}", MVCt4.TerminalArea.OutboundPattern.Index(), new {id = String.Empty});
```

I get a runtime error? I have this code in the global.asax file and it works fine:

```
   static public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // do not allow any body access our our resources
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");

        // home url ok
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "Home/{action}/{id}", MVCt4.Home.Index(), new {id = String.Empty});
```

}

In the areas it does not work put the main global asa it works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a example on how to use the t4mvc on the code plex site.

[codeplex](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/)